# Can anyone tell me the difference between two functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Function #1:

```
setPeople(peoples.filter(people => people.id !== item.id)
```

function #2:

```
setPeople(prevState => {
    return prevState.filter(people => people.id !== item.id)
})
```

And which is better?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: *Better* - how? Define your criteria for what is "better" ...

Comment: See it [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `setPeople` is defined like this:

```
const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
```

then there is only one *semantic* different (that is, a difference in the operation of the program).  It’s easier to see if use a different type.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
setCount(3);
setCount(count + 1);
```

will result in `count` being set to 2, while

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
setCount(3);
setCount(c => c + 1);
```

will result in `count` being set to 4.  If you think about it a while, you will see why.

The distinction between

```
x => x + 1
```

and

```
x => {
   return x + 1;
}
```

is purely esthetic.  I prefer the former, but YMMV.